Postgresql JSONB column - Index - GIN Vs BTree
I have a large table with multiple partitions (total size = 250 GB). The table has a column with a large json stored as a jsonb column. Users will query using criteria on certain fields (one or multiple) and also sort data based on usage.
Please suggest if its a good practice to setup BTREE indexes or do I need to evaluate GIN index on the jsonb column for better performance and management.
We setup BTREE indexes individually on the specific fields in the JSON. The BTREE indexes work well but it does add more maintenance in that we need to set it up based on usage and also on this large table that takes hours to execute and implement.
